# Getting/generating an image from embedded flash video

Tags: php, flash, video, embedded-resource, thumbnails

So what I am curious about is if it is possible and how, to have an embedded video and capture the thumbnail.  There are other sites that share video and I'd like to get the thumbnails from the embedded videos, but they use flash video players to show the video and likely use flashvars to pull up the right video.

I appreciate any help here. I've been trying to automate some of the capture of thumbnails and embedded videos but have no clue how to get remote thumbnails from these videos.

Answer (score 0):

[JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/) has a ["snapshot" plugin](http://www.longtailvideo.com/addons/plugins/96/Snapshot) that can be set up to take snapshots in the movie, and send them to a server side script.

Answer (score 0):

within flash is pretty easy, since the Video object implements IBitmapDrawable, you can have a snapshot of it using [BitmapData.draw()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use some tool to extract the FLV from swf, it lays in DefineVideoStream, and VideoFrame tags.You can write it yourself using some library for managing swf content.After that use FFMPEG for getting the right frame.